# Add to a list based on property in an object

Tags: java, if-statement, java-stream, filtering

```
private static CodeList prepareChangeObject(CodeList codeList, CodeList existingCodeList, boolean dataExists)
            throws EntityValidationException {
        CodeList UpdatedCodeList = new CodeList();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(codeList, UpdatedCodeList);
        Set<CodeListData> updatedDataList =UpdatedCodeList.getData().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        updatedDataList.addAll(existingCodeList.getData());
        List<CodeListData> finalData = updatedDataList.stream().collect(
                collectingAndThen(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparing(CodeListData::getKey))), ArrayList::new));
        finalData = finalData.stream().filter(data -> {
            if (data.getOperation() == null)
                data.setOperation(MetaConstants.OPERATION_ADD);
            if (null != data.getOperation()) {
                if (data.getOperation().equals(MetaConstants.OPERATION_DELETE) && dataExists)
                    exceptionMessagesList.add(
                            new ExceptionMessage("foundation.OperationNotAllowed", new String[] { data.getKey() }));
                if (data.getOperation().equals(MetaConstants.OPERATION_DELETE) && !dataExists)
                    return false;
                if (data.getOperation().equals(MetaConstants.OPERATION_ADD))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        UpdatedCodeList.setData(finalData);
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(exceptionMessagesList))
            throw new EntityValidationException(HTTPClientError.BAD_REQUEST, exceptionMessagesList);
        return UpdatedCodeList;
    }
```

1.The above method should return a change object based on the operation specified.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException, EntityValidationException {
    String jsonPost = "{\n"
            + "  \"id\": \"temperature101\",\n"
            + "  \"descriptions\": [\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"languageCode\": \"en\",\n"
            + "      \"description\": \"description\",\n"
            + "      \"longDescription\": \"long description\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"languageCode\": \"de\",\n"
            + "      \"description\": \"description\",\n"
            + "      \"longDescription\": \"long description\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  ],\n"
            + "  \"dataType\": \"String\",\n"
            + "  \"data\": [\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"key\": \"val1\",\n"
            + "      \"value\": \"High\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"key\": \"val4\",\n"
            + "      \"value\": \"Medium\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"key\": \"val3\",\n"
            + "      \"value\": \"Low\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  ]\n"
            + "}";
    String jsonPatch = "{\n"
            + "  \"id\": \"temperature101\",\n"
            + "  \"descriptions\": [\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"languageCode\": \"en\",\n"
            + "      \"description\": \"description1\",\n"
            + "      \"longDescription\": \"long description1\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"languageCode\": \"de\",\n"
            + "      \"description\": \"description1\",\n"
            + "      \"longDescription\": \"long description1\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  ],\n"
            + "  \"dataType\": \"String\",\n"
            + "  \"data\": [\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"key\": \"val1\",\n"
            + "      \"value\": \"High\",\n"
            + "      \"operation\": \"DELETE\"\n"
            + "\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    {\n"
            + "      \"key\": \"val4\",\n"
            + "      \"value\": \"Medium\",\n"
            + "      \"operation\": \"DELETE\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  ]\n"
            + "}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CodeList ExistingodeList = mapper.readValue(jsonPost, CodeList.class);
    CodeList currentCodeList = mapper.readValue(jsonPatch, CodeList.class);
    CodeList upDatetedCodeList = prepareChangeObject(currentCodeList, ExistingodeList, false);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(upDatetedCodeList.toString());
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(upDatetedCodeList));
    
}
```

2. the above main method to test the code

```
@Data
public class CodeListData {
    
    @Column("ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;
    
    @Column("KEY")
    private String key;
    
    @Column("VALUE")
    private String value;
    
    @Column("ETAG")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String etag;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column("VERSION")
    @Version
    private Long version;
    
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String operation;

}
```

3. Pojo for reference

```
@Data
public class CodeList implements Persistable<String>{

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    private String id;
    
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "ID", keyColumn = "ID_SEQ")
    private List<CodeListDescriptions> descriptions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Column("DATA_TYPE")
    private String dataType;
    
    @Column("LENGTH")
    private String length;
    
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "ID", keyColumn = "ID_SEQ")
    private List<CodeListData> data = new ArrayList<CodeListData>();
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column("VERSION")
    private Long version;
    
    @Column("ETAG")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String etag;
    
    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    @Setter
    private boolean isInsert;

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isInsert;
    }
}
```

4.codeList pojo

```
@Data
public class CodeListDescriptions{

    @Column("ISO")
    public String languageCode;
    
    @Column("DESCRIPTION")
    public String description;
    
    @Column("LONG_DESCRIPTION")
    public String longDescription;
    
    @Column("ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;

}
```

5.final output required is only `"val3"` to be present. The method is supposed to remove or add based on the operations `DELETE` or `ADD`. The issue is that val4 is still in the output because when the finalData is created it prefers to keep the `"val4"` from existing data which does not contain any operation. The final output needs to contain the added values and values not specified in the payload but exists in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

> it prefers to keep the val4 from existing data which does not contain any operation

you are defaulting to the `add` operation with this code, so regardless of whether or not there is an operation, you explicitly set one

```
if (data.getOperation() == null)
  data.setOperation(MetaConstants.OPERATION_ADD);
```

Then you check it like

```
if (null != data.getOperation()) { // this is always true, because you use the default one line before
  ...
  if (data.getOperation().equals(MetaConstants.OPERATION_ADD))
    return true;
}
```

so in the end the final

```
return false;
```

will never be reached.

Comment: "don't use equals for Enums" those seem to be Strings for which `equals` is the correct choice.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I guess I skipped over it when reading and I just assumed it base on how I would handle it. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You create a `Set<CodeListData>` from both the existing and the update data set. `CodeListData` defines its `equals` and `hashCode` methods over all fields. Note that Lombok ignores `transient` fields, but those a different from fields annotated with `@Transient`. So you have `val4` twice in the `Set` once with `DELETE` operation and once without any operation. The one with `DELETE` will get filtered out, but the one with no operation will default to `ADD` and stay in the `SET`.

Note: I consider it unfortunate to name a variable of type `Set` anything that ends in `List`.